# Using Dictionary to Cut-Out Parts of Strings in a List

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary, replace

I have a long list that is generated using Beautiful Soup in Python 3.

Right now, the list is generated as so..

```
mylist = [a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True) if a.text]
```

It's a web scraping thing, but just know it returns a list.

And in the form of a list, it returns results such as these:

> 'catalogue/category/books/travel_2/index.html',
>
> 'catalogue/category/books/mystery_3/index.html',
>
> 'catalogue/category/books/historical-fiction_4/index.html'

Before I print my list, I'd like to remove various useless information (such as "catalogue/", "category/" and "books/", so that only the important information is displayed (travel, mystery or historical fiction).

I was able to replace one thing successfully using:

```
mylist = [item.replace("catalogue/category/", "") for item in mylist]
```

Which worked great. But I don't believe .replace will take more than 2 arguments, which leaves me unable to remove additional things from my results such as "index.html" . I'd rather not write that line for everything I want to replace. That's why I'm trying to use keys and values from a dictionary as the .replace() arguments:

```
replacedict = {"catalogue/category/": "" , "index.html": ""}

mylist = [a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True) if a.text]

def replace_all(mylist, replacedict):
     for k, v in replacedict.items():
         mylist = [item.replace(k, v) for item in mylist]
     return mylist

replace_all(mylist, replacedict)

print(mylist)
```

Right now, the program isn't throwing any errors when it's run. But it's also simply NOT doing what i'm asking of it. It's just returning a large list of results shown above with nothing removed or replaced out of them.

Very confused, although I'm sure the answer is right in front of me.

Appreciate any and all help, couldn't find a question quite like this one anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using regular expression?

```
import re

my_list = ['catalogue/category/books/travel_2/index.html', 'catalogue/category/books/mystery_3/index.html', 'catalogue/category/books/historical-fiction_4/index.html']

REGEX = r'(catalogue/|category/|books/|_\d+/index.html)'

my_list = [re.sub(REGEX, '', string) for string in my_list]

print(my_list)
```

Output:

```
['travel', 'mystery', 'historical-fiction']
```

Comment: This worked great. Any tips on removing the _3 and _4s? Assuming this list was huge.

Comment: Was able to remove the _3 and _4s using: mylist = [i.split('_')[0] for i in mylist]

Comment: @jonthesupreme I updated the answer to remove _3 like suffixes without additional list traversal

Answer (score 0):

Why not just get the part of each URL that you're interested in by splitting the string into a list of strings.  E.g.:

```
$ python
Python 3.7.2 (default, Dec 27 2018, 07:35:06) 
[Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> string_list = ['catalogue/category/books/travel_2/index.html', 'catalogue/category/books/mystery_3/index.html', 'catalogue/category/books/historical-fiction_4/index.html']
>>> array_list = [s.split('/') for s in string_list]
>>> array_list
[['catalogue', 'category', 'books', 'travel_2', 'index.html'], ['catalogue', 'category', 'books', 'mystery_3', 'index.html'], ['catalogue', 'category', 'books', 'historical-fiction_4', 'index.html']]
>>> [a[3] for a in array_list]
['travel_2', 'mystery_3', 'historical-fiction_4']
```

That should work if the URLs are always structured the way you've shown.